# Scroll to specific page of PDF in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a PDF displayed in an iframe (cross-domain), and want to programmatically scroll to a particular page when a user clicks on a link that contains the text for which page to scroll to.

When I try to set the vertical position of the scrollbar however, nothing happens.

```
$('iframe').animate({
  scrollTop: 5000
}, 100);
```

Forcing the iframe to reload to a different page as follows works, but can take a long time if the PDF file is large.

```
<p>Page: <a href="#" class="go_to_page">4</a></p>

$(document).on('click', '.go_to_page', function (） {
  var pageNum = $(this).text().trim();
  $('iframe')[0].src = $('iframe')[0].src + '#page=' + pageNum;
})
```

Is there a better way of doing this?